TailwindCSS xs breakpoint overrides everything else
Using something like "xs:hidden md:block" will stay hidden at the md: size for some reason.
Here's a playtailwind link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/CAY0v1N8oa
Most people say this is because ordering matters on the config but as you can see my config should be fine:
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: '32rem',
        sm: '48rem',
        md: '75rem',
        lg: '92rem',
        xl: '112rem',
      },
    },
  },
}


anyone that needs a workaround you can use "hidden xs:block sm:!hidden" for now

You should not use an xs declaration as it is the default anyway. Declare the general style such as hidden and then a style with a breakpoint to modify it for that breakpoint: https://play.tailwindcss.com/qMtNB1vgrY

Using rem values is the issue here but I dont think it should be. Made an issue on Tailwindcss's github.

I messed up the play, updated the link @tacoshy

For some reason, when I remove 'theme extend' inside tailwind config, it is working properly.

Someone had a similar problem that was posted as an issue on GitHub, here's the solution posted as a reply.
